# Remove stop words from a string without trimming other words in Swift

Tags: swift, string

I am using the following code to remove **Stop words** from string but it ends up **trimming** other words, I just want to **remove the specific words** from a string without trimming other words.

```
 import Foundation

var sentence = "God have created the creatures at his best"
let wordToRemove = "at"


if let range = sentence.range(of: wordToRemove) {
   sentence.removeSubrange(range)
}

print(sentence) // God have creed the creures  his best
```

Comment: My desired output is = "God have created the creatures his best"

Comment: Just look for " at " instead of "at"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First write an extenstion of Build-In class String

```
extension String {

    func contains(word : String) -> Range<String.Index>?
    {
        return self.range(of: "\\b\(word)\\b", options: .regularExpression)
    }
}
```

Then write the below code to remove the specific word from a sentence

```
var sentence = "God have created the creatures at his best"
let wordToRemove = "at"

if let range  = sentence.contains(word: wordToRemove) {
     sentence.removeSubrange(range)
     print(sentence)
}

 //Output : God have created the creatures  his best
```

Comment: I'd think the regular expression would be rather costly on performance. Also, he wanted a solution to remove multiple stop words.

Answer (score 1):

By my understanding of stop words, they can occur at any point in the sentence, including as the first or last word.  So a solution should support removing them anywhere in the sentence.

```
import Foundation

var sentence = "at God have created the creatures at his best at"
let wordsToRemove = ["at", "his"]

let words = sentence.components(separatedBy: " ")
sentence = words.filter({ wordsToRemove.contains($0) == false }).joined(separator:" ")

// sentence is now "God have created the creatures best"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import Foundation

var sentence = "God have created the creatures at at at at his best"
let words = [" at ", " his "]
var index = 0
while index < words.count {
    let word = words[index]
    if let range = sentence.range(of: word) {
        sentence = sentence.replacingOccurrences(of: word, with: " ", options: [], range: range)
    } else {
        index += 1
    }
}

print(sentence)
```

> God have created the creatures best

Comment: Doesn't support stop words at front and end of sentence.

Answer (score 0):

```
func replaceText(){
        var sentence = "At God have created the creatures at his best aatckkat at."
        var arr = [String]()
        sentence.enumerateSubstrings(in: sentence.startIndex..<sentence.endIndex, options: .byWords) { (str, r1, r2, stop) in
            //Condition for words to be removed
            if str! != "at" && str! != "At"{
                arr.append(str!)
            }
        }
        sentence = ""
        for word in arr{
            sentence += "\(word) "
        }
        print("new altered sentence -> \(sentence)")
    }
```

You can try this way out.